# Adding header tags ruins my template?

Tags: php, html, templates

I have added an availability calendar to my website which I found online, the header tags are below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/dateTimePicker.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/components/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/dateTimePicker.min.js"></script>
```

When I add them to my current website page, it changes the template and ruins the look by either adding blank white space at the top of the page or affecting the nav bar whenever I add the script? Any ideas how I can have the script without it affecting my template? 
Here is my template html with the script added...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css">
<title>Dave's Caravan Letting</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rochester' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/dateTimePicker.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/components/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/dateTimePicker.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: conflict on the style on the css files probably

Answer (score 0):

By adding random code to existing code can cause code conflict, first understood the existing css code and than add the additional css code.

If you want to debug then open the site in browser's developer tool, check out the portion's css using inspect element and correct or rectify the css code.

Use the following link to learn how to use developer tool
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools